# SQL get available times for users on the same team

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables:

1. userfree
2. teamroster

The userfree table has the following columns

1. uniqueid - A_I unique id for this item
2. userid - user id number
3. id - unique id per user event generated by calendar (so if user has 5 free times it will be (1-5)
4. start - start timedate user is free
5. end - end timedate user is free

The teamroster table has the following columns

1. id - A_I unique id for this item
2. teamid - id for the team they belong to
3. userid - id of user who is on this team

What I need to do is find all overlapping times for users who are on the same team. Before I added in the team stuff I had some sql to find users with overlapping times:

```
SELECT dr1.uniqueid as ida, dr2.uniqueid as idb, dr1.userid as userida, dr2.userid as useridb, dr2.start, dr2.end 
FROM `userfree` dr2
INNER JOIN `userfree` dr1
WHERE
  dr2.start >= dr1.start AND
  dr2.start <= dr1.end AND
  dr1.uniqueid != dr2.uniqueid AND
  dr1.userid != dr2.userid
ORDER BY dr2.start
```

I tried a couple things, but I am thinking I am going about it the wrong way and figured I would ask on here. Besides my method may be a less efficient one.

Comment: I think added sample data and output contemplating the different cases would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to join each `userfree` onto it's own `teamroster` and then compare `teamids`.

```
select
    dr1.uniqueid as ida, 
    dr2.uniqueid as idb, 
    dr1.userid as userida, 
    dr2.userid as useridb, 
    dr2.start, 
    dr2.end 
from
    `userfree` dr2
        inner join
    `teamroster` r2
        on dr2.userid = r2.userid
        cross join
    `userfree` dr1
        inner join
    `teamroster` r1
        on dr1.userid = r1.userid
Where
    dr2.start >= dr1.start and
    dr2.start <= dr1.end and
    dr1.uniqueid != dr2.uniqueid and
    dr1.userid != dr2.userid and
    r1.teamid = r2.teamid
order by
    dr2.start
```